# object detection using tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, image-processing, tensorflow.js

I am using js to remove pixels from a video frame captured onto a canvas and exported to imagedata
[image: sample]

It works to a certain extent, however I have been introduced to tensorflow.js and specifically the object detection api.

I'm wondering if anyone has tensforflow.js experience and can advise if it can be used this way to detect people objects in an image so ultimately I end up with an image with just people?

Comment: You can use the [segmentation model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix) to change the background. But if your goal is only to remove a single color, you have to make sure the color is not part of other objects or shape you would like to keep. Specifically here, you only want to remove the grass color. But if that color is present in the players, the color would be removed as well